# sql: simple question, how to see data from columns with similar names?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

With this query on mysql I can see the delete_priv value

```
select user,Delete_priv  from user ;
```

I see there is a lot of _priv columns, how to see all priv values?
I have tried

```
select user,*_priv  from user ;
select user,%%priv%% from user;
```

But is wrong syntax.

Comment: You have a problem with your data model if you have lots of columns storing such similar information.  In any case, SQL has no generic substitution of column names in queries.

Comment: No. You need to enumerate all the column names (or use `select *`, and get *all* the columns in the table).

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's not his data model, it looks like it's the built-in `mysql.user` table.

Comment: GMB, please add as answer, so I can vote and close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

In standard SQL, you need to enumerate all names of the columns you want to `select`. Or, you can use `select *`, and get *all* the columns in the table.

Alternatively, you can use dynamic SQL: that is, write a query that searches `information_schema.columns` and generates the list of columns that matches your filter, concatenate a query string from that, then execute it. But this is really a more complex beast, that is probably overkill for your use case.

Comment: You could write dynamic SQL that enumerates the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.